# CharacterController.velocity всегда возвращает 0

Tags: unity3d

В update проверяю velocity так:

```
Vector3 moveVector = (cam.transform.right * joystick.Horizontal + cam.transform.forward * joystick.Vertical);
            moveVector.y = 0.0f;
            moveSpeed *= moveVector.magnitude;
            if (controller.isGrounded) {
                    controller.Move (moveVector * moveSpeed * moveVector.magnitude * Time.deltaTime);
                    if (cam.transform.localPosition.y <= -0.01f && timeout <= 0f) {
                            PlayStepSound ();
                            timeout = 0.6f;
                    }
            }
            controller.SimpleMove (Physics.gravity * 3 * Time.deltaTime);
            Debug.Log (controller.velocity);
```

Но всегда возвращает (0, 0, 0), однако если поднять персонажа, то velocity по оси y реагирует и отображается корректно. В чем проблема?

Comment: Так это 2д игра или 3д?

Comment: @TEA 3d игра (символы)

Comment: @Vefery, поставьте брейк поинт и проверьте расчёты на всех этапах. У вас вообще заходит в задание движения? controller.isGrounded в true переходит?

Comment: @M. Green, да переходит, я спокойно передвигаюсь